# Find the digit represented by C.

Tags: cryptarithm

I am self-studying Multiplication and Division. This is a problem I encountered and have hard time with it. I have no clue where to start. In fact, I have read this problem many times, wondering whether it is a valid problem.

> In the division problem, the letters a, b, c, d, and e represent five different digits. Find the digit represented by c.
>
> [image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:division-algebras]. Please read the tag wiki before using a tag you are unfamiliar with. In math we frequently give a common sounding word a very technical meaning, so newbies will go astray, if they add tags that just *feel vaguely relevant*.

Comment: To answer this you need to specify the division problem. Without it, there isn't enough information to answer this.

Comment: There should be a picture or figure that accompanies the question. Without it, there is no way to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second subtraction implies $e=2$ and $d=3$. Also, $a \cdot b = 35$. So either $a=5$ or $a=7$.

If $a=7$, then the first subtraction does not make sense since $c-a=3$ implies $c=10$, but $c$ has to be a single digit. Thus $a=5$ and $c=a+3=8$.